# Python Dataframes merge multi match

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, multiple-columns

I'm new with Dataframe.
I would like to kwon how (if possible) can I merge 2 Dataframes with multiple match
For example

```
[df1]

date                  ZipCode Weather
2022-11-25 00:00:00   123456   34
2022-11-25 00:00:15   123456   35
2022-11-25 00:00:30   123456   36
```

```
[df2]
date                  ZipCode   host
2022-11-25 00:00:00   123456   host1
2022-11-25 00:00:00   123456   host2
2022-11-25 00:00:00   123456   host3
2022-11-25 00:00:15   123456   host1
2022-11-25 00:00:30   123456   host2
2022-11-25 00:00:30   123456   host3
```

Expected results:

```
date                  ZipCode   host   Weather
2022-11-25 00:00:00   123456   host1   34
2022-11-25 00:00:00   123456   host2   34
2022-11-25 00:00:00   123456   host3   34
2022-11-25 00:00:15   123456   host1   35
2022-11-25 00:00:30   123456   host2   36
2022-11-25 00:00:30   123456   host3   36
```

My objetive is assign weather measures to each host.
I have weather measurements every 15 minutes for one ZipCode (One line)
By the other hand, I have several host KPIs for one time and one ZipCode (multiples lines)

Can I perfomr this activity with Dataframes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the join function in pandas which joins one dataframe's index to the index of the other. Try something like

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = \
[['2022-11-25 00:00:00',  123456, 34],
['2022-11-25 00:00:15',  123456, 35],
['2022-11-25 00:00:30',  123456, 36]]

columns1 =['date', 'ZipCode', 'Weather']

data2 = \
[['2022-11-25 00:00:00',  123456, 'host1'],
['2022-11-25 00:00:00',  123456, 'host2'],
['2022-11-25 00:00:00',  123456, 'host3'],
['2022-11-25 00:00:15',  123456, 'host1'],
['2022-11-25 00:00:30',  123456, 'host2'],
['2022-11-25 00:00:30',  123456, 'host3']]

columns2 =['date', 'ZipCode', 'host']

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1, columns=columns1)
df1.date = pd.to_datetime(df1.date)
df1.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2, columns=columns2)
df2.date = pd.to_datetime(df2.date)
df2.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df3 = df1.join(df2['host'], on='date')
df3
```

Comment: Thanks! Function correctly. The problem that Im facing is with the lines that dont match, for example no date in data1 but a host in data2. With this solution only persist in df3 all matches, not only "enrich" the matches, is possible do that?

Answer (score 0):

We do that by using `merge` and setting the argument `on` to `['date', 'ZipCode']`:

```
new_df = pd.merge(df2, df1, on=['date', 'ZipCode'])
```

**Output**

```
>>> new_df
...      date           ZipCode host    Weather
0   2022-11-25 00:00:00 123456  host1   34
1   2022-11-25 00:00:00 123456  host2   34
2   2022-11-25 00:00:00 123456  host3   34
3   2022-11-25 00:00:15 123456  host1   35
4   2022-11-25 00:00:30 123456  host2   36
5   2022-11-25 00:00:30 123456  host3   36
```

Comment: Thanks! Function correctly but the problem with the missmatch persist. Im trying to use that to "play" with machine learning algorithms and in this cases I only have "match cases". I would like to have all my host and enrich them with the weather related, If I dont have weather, persist the line with the host with empty weather

Answer (score 0):

After several test I got the expected result

```
new_df2 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['date', 'ZipCode'], how='right')
```

Thanks for your orientation!!